# How to restart a function from inside it

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to restart the function non() with the if statement inside. I have looked at other sources and none of them seem to work. here is my code. It's in French btw.

```js
var click = 9;

function non() {
  var i;
  var message = document.getElementById("message");

  //Affiche un message chaque fois que le bouton non //estcliquer
  for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    message.innerHTML += "Es-tu près !!OUI!! ou !!NON!!<br>";
  }

  if (!(click--)) {
    alert("Es-tu près");
    non();
  }

  document.getElementById("boutonNon").click;
}
```

```html
<div id="divNon">
  <button class="bouton boutonOui" id="boutonNon"
      onclick="non()" value="reset">Non</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("boutonNon").click` doesn't do anything.  You forgot to call the function.

Comment: If you want to keep calling a function until some condition is fulfilled, don't call the function from inside itself (this is called recursion and has its uses but not in this case). Rather, use a `while` or `do until` loop instead. Plus, is it possible you don't actually want a loop here? Because as you can see from the "fixes" posted below, the resulting behavior seems pretty useless.

Comment: You can probably do without that `for` loop since it only ever runs once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could remove the loop and use a recursive function that calls out to a promise and waits till it resolves before it fires again.

The HTML children will not be added until all the alerts have been accepted.

```js
var message = document.getElementById("message");
var clicksRemaining = 9;

const handleClick = () => new Promise(res => {
  message.append(document
    .createTextNode(`${clicksRemaining}) Es-tu près !!OUI!! ou !!NON!!`));
  message.append(document.createElement('br'));
  alert("Es-tu près");
  res();
});

function non() {
  handleClick().then(() => {
    if (clicksRemaining --> 1) {
      non();
    }
  });
}

document.getElementById('boutonNon').click();
```

```html
<div id="divNon">
  <button class="bouton boutonOui" id="boutonNon"
      onclick="non()" value="reset">Non</button>
</div>
<div id="message"></div>
```